# Can't create objects with an interval in Libgdx

Tags: java, multithreading, libgdx

I am developing a space ship game.

I have an EnemyFactory class to create enemies with this method:

```
   public void createPattern(String patternJson, final String enemyJson, final Vector2 position) {
    System.out.println(TAG + "- Entering pattern creation..");
    Json json = new Json();
    final ObjectMap objectMap = json.fromJson(ObjectMap.class, Gdx.files.internal(patternJson));

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            float count = Float.parseFloat(objectMap.get("count").toString());
            float interval = Float.parseFloat(objectMap.get("interval").toString());
            float intervalDelta = 0;

            System.out.println(TAG + "- Running thread..");

            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                do{
                    intervalDelta += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
                    System.out.println(TAG + "- interval => " + intervalDelta);
                }while(intervalDelta < interval);

                Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println(TAG + "- creating enemy ship..");
                        createEnemy(enemyJson, position);
                    }
                });

                intervalDelta = 0;
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

The idea is to create  5enemies in an interval of time (0.5s) but when i run the app, it runs the for loop 5 times and then creates 5 enemies but without interval of time.

Any suggestion?

EDIT:

I'd made another version of the function:

```
    public void createPattern(String patternJson, final String enemyJson, final Vector2 position) {
    System.out.println(TAG + "- Entering pattern creation..");
    Json json = new Json();
    final ObjectMap objectMap = json.fromJson(ObjectMap.class, Gdx.files.internal(patternJson));
    float count = Float.parseFloat(objectMap.get("count").toString());
    float interval = Float.parseFloat(objectMap.get("interval").toString());
    float intervalDelta = 0;

    Timer timer = Timer.instance();
    timer.scheduleTask(new Timer.Task() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            createEnemy(enemyJson, position);
        }
    },0,interval,(int) count);
}
```

and this is what happends, still not the desired behaviour:

[image: test]

Comment: Maybe you should run game mechanics on the render thread? (I mean, that is how most games are designed)

Comment: Also in your thread busy waiting with `do...while` is not good practice because it puts unnecessary strain on the CPU. Try `Thread.sleep` or `Thread.yield` (Preferably sleep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code for you task.

Pay attention for **[TimeUnit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html)** class, very useful for tasks with delay.

---

```
public class ScheduledExecution {

    public void createEnemyByPattern() {

        EnemyActivator factory = new EnemyActivator(5, 500);

        new Thread(factory).start();

    }

}

class EnemyActivator implements Runnable {

    private final int enemyCount;
    private final long creationDelay;

    EnemyActivator(int enemyCount, long creationDelay) {
        this.enemyCount = enemyCount;
        this.creationDelay = creationDelay;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for(int i=0; i<enemyCount; ++i) {
            activateEnemy();
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(creationDelay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private void activateEnemy() {
        // create and send enemy code here
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you provided it's not possible to tell what's wrong - it could be something outside your code. But, following good game programming practice, I suggest you use the following:

```
public class MyGameClass <extends Game|implements ApplicationListener|whatever> {
  // ...
  float totalDelta=0;
  float mechanicsDelta= // your interval here
  float shipCount=0, totalShips= // count goes here
  public void render(){
    totalDelta+=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    int mechanicsFrames=0;
    while(totalDelta>mechanicsDelta){
      if(shipCount<totalShips){
        // spawn ship
        shipCount++;
      }
      // more game mechanics here
      if(mechanicsFrames>4){
        System.out.println("Warning: FPS is too low! Skipping frames...");
        // on a normal system this shouldn't happen
        // but in case it does we can't have your game freeze
        // insert some graceful error out here
        break;
      }
      mechanicsFrames++;
    }
    // render here
  }

  // ...
}
```

Also consider using `Pool<...>` for your enemy ships as instantiating/garbage collecting objects is slow.